# Access Error Object at Error Middleware Handler

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

This is my custom error validation code :

```
            .custom(async (username) => {
                const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username })
                if (user) throw new ConflictError('username already used')
                return true
            }),
```

and this is my Validation Handler code :

```
    const validatePayload = (): RequestHandler => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            const result = validationResult(req)
            if (result.isEmpty()) return next()

            const error = result.array()[0]
            const msg = `${error.msg} at ${error.param}`
            throw new ValidationError(msg)
        }
    }
```

The point is, i want to access ConflictError Object in my Validation and thus i can use ConflictError property to properly send error message and status

Answer (score 2):

I do not know where you call your custom validation. Assuming it is called somewhere in ValidationResult(req), you might try this :

```
const validatePayload = (): RequestHandler => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        try{
            const result = validationResult(req)
            if (result.isEmpty()) return next()
        }
        catch(e) {
            if(e instanceof ConflictError) {
                const error = result.array()[0]
                const msg = `${error.msg} at ${error.param}`
                throw new ValidationError(msg)
            }
            if(e instanceof AnotherError) {
                // do another thing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what i meant, but thank you for answering, already solved it 

Comment: Add your own answer to help others